# Disprove $A^C∪B^C⊆(A∪B)^C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

> Suppose A and B are sets, and $x∈A^C∪B^C$. Then $x∈A^C$ or $x∈B^C$ by
>   definition of union. It follows that $x∉A$ or $x∉B$ by definition of
>   complement, and so $x∉A∪B$ by definition of union. Thus $x∈(A∪B)^C$ by
>   definition of complement, and hence $A^C∪B^C⊆(A∪B)^C$.”

Is the transition from $x \notin A \cup B$ to $x \in (A \cup B)^c$ false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a universe that contains two objects $0$ and $1$. With $ A = \{0\} $ and $ B = \{ 1 \} $. It would follow that  $ A^C \cup B^C = \{ 0,1\}$.  However $ \{ A \cup B\}^C = \emptyset $

The mistake you made is that the definition of union $A \cup B = \{ x : x \in A \vee x \in B \} $ says nothing about  $x \notin A $.  If you wished to work from the definitions  this is the way you would do it.

$$ \begin{align} ( A \cup B)^C &= \{ x : x \in A \vee x \in B \}^C\\ &= \{ x : \overline{x \in A \vee x \in B} \}\\
&= \{x: x \notin A \wedge x \notin B\} \end{align}$$

The last step being due to demorgains law.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know what is error in the quoted sentences.

Comment: I made an edit that I hope more fully answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$ is true. But saying that implies $x \notin A \cup B$ is false. (Consider the case where $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$ or the case where $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$.)

Comment: Does that mean x applies only to $x \notin A $ or $ x \in B$?

Comment: I mean, we can have the case where both $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$. This satisfies the first condition where $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$ since we have $x \notin A$, but it fails to satisfy the second case $x \notin A \cup B$, since $x \in B$. (The second case I offered $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ is the same as the first, with $A$ and $B$ flipped.)

Comment: Can you clarify as where it states that $x \notin A \cup B$ is false?

Comment: We have x in $B$, so x is also in $A \cup B$, by definition of the union.